# Identifying SMPS transformer

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, identification

I have a SMPS acting weirdly and I believe to be caused by its transformer. I need to find a replacement but I'm having trouble identifying it.

[image: SMPS transformer: pri: 240V, sec1: 12V, sec2: 24V, aux:10-27V]

The marking has too lines: 1st containing the **VDE** logo followed by **30090314**, 2nd containing **REG.-Nr. E895 CH 20 18**. I know "VDE" stands for VDE Association, most likely indicating the standards by which it was built/tested. The rest of the info reveals nothing.

Its external dimensions are 34mm x 23mm x 21mm. It is a through-hole component, soldered on a PCB labeled **VESTEL 17IPS12 R3**, for which I found a generic schematic. In an effort to identify the cause of the problem, I replaced and changed parts to reflect the actual circuit.

[image: VESTEL 17IPS12 R3 - adapted to the circuit]

The primary can take up to 240V or more. It has 3 secondaries: one for 12V, another for 24V and an auxiliary with no voltage mention in the schematic but from the controller's specs (FAN6300A) I can infer it can be anything from 10V to 27V. Also, the controller can work with frequencies up to 100kHz.

Searching on mouser and digikey gave one candidate: [ECO2425SEO-D01V019](https://mm.digikey.com/Volume0/opasdata/d220001/medias/docus/668/ECOxyyyySEO_SLD.pdf). However, this doesn't seem to have a suitable AUX voltage.

Also, since the circuit seems to be popular I can assume there's a at least small marked for parts but I could not find results in conjunction with the circuit info. Other similar circuits seem to have transformers with other markings, suggesting brands (LiShin) or containing Thermal class B.

Can anyone suggest what else to look for?

**Update**

I made 4 measurement, all having on channel 1 the drain-GND signal for trigger and timing reference. On the 2nd channel I captured CS-GND, then DET-GND both before and after modifying the voltage dividers. For obvious safety reasons, all measurements were made with the DUT powered through an isolation transformer.

Before anything I wanted to catch the moment the switching stops when I found the controller's Vcc pin to have a stable 16V. I then probed the DET pin and, after the blanking interval (4us), there's clearly more than 2.5V. All these check against the R210, (R211 + R212) divider ratio (6.4). According the the FAN6300A datasheet, a DET voltage above 2.5V is sufficient to latch it off.

[image: FAN6300A stopping with 16V on Vcc]

*FAN6300A stopping with 16V on Vcc*

Based on the above measurements I assumed the feedback output voltage doesn't reach 12V in time and causes the DET to trigger OVP latch-off. The timeout for lack of FB signal (55ms) seems generous enough not to cause problems. With the 24V rail disconnected and all 12V output rectifier diodes, capacitors (well within tolerance and nearly zero ESR) and the entire feedback network (including optocupler) checked, the high-voltage rail also having a stable 340V (with capacitors and rectifier bridge checked as well), I further assumed something else causing the slow to catch-up output. The only culprit, in my opinion, was the transformer.

The following captures are made for the circuit in its original form.

[image: FAN6300A - ch1: MOSFET's drain-GND voltage, ch2: CS-GND voltage, 2us time base]

*Channel 1: MOSFET's drain-GND voltage, Channel 2: CS-GND voltage*

[image: FAN6300A - ch1: MOSFET's drain-GND voltage, ch2: DET-GND voltage, 2us time base]

*Channel 1: MOSFET's drain-GND voltage, Channel 2: DET-GND voltage*

I then got the idea of altering the divider network for the DET voltage, such that it doesn't trigger OVP anymore yet keeping Vcc below 27V (the other OVP threshold). I placed 2 resistors (51k and 47k) in parallel with the R210. This caused the 12V rail to raise higher but still not enough to generate feedback. I then altered the divider (one 51k resistor in parallel with R122) feeding the TL431 on the feedback such that it lowered the output voltage. This proved successful in the sense that there was feedback and a rather constant output voltage. Nothing overheated (or worse) for the approx. 5 minutes I kept the circuit on.

The following was taken for the modified circuit.

[image: Circuit with modified dividers - ch1: MOSFET's drain-GND voltage, ch2: DET-GND voltage, 2us time base]

*Circuit with modified dividers - Channel 1: MOSFET's drain-GND voltage, Channel 2: DET-GND voltage*

I was glad to see the controller entering extended-valley mode to cope with the low current drawn by a LED + its limiting resistor.
That said, the circuit still seems to have long pauses (~1s) between trains of switching pulses. Probably, I could further adjust divider networks such that the Vcc reaches and remains between around 17-24V (assuming that's the cause of the pauses).

All those, of course, are made for testing purposes and to confirm/infirm suppositions but I would like to understand what's happening and eventually fix the unit.

Comment: SMPS transformers are usually custom-made. It's rare to find an off-line SMPS with an off-the-shelf transformer. What makes you suspect that the transformer is bad? They're just wire wound on a core and are therefore rather robust, so before they die, everything else in the circuit is already charcoal.

Comment: I feared this might be the case but hoped somehow standard transformers may exist. The 12V and 24V are common and the SMPS in question has been used in many consumer electronic units. Answering the second question, all parts surrounding the transformer are good. I was able to adjust voltage dividers around the transformer to bring the SMPS back to live (reduced the feedback output to from 12V to 7V and the DET voltage from AUX output). My only guess is that neighboring transformer turns have somehow shorted, creating an imbalance that threw the controller in a failure latching mode.

Comment: That's possible, but unlikely. A shorted turn causes extreme power dissipation in the transformer, which usually leads to melting / burning. It's more likely that one of the surrounding components is degraded. Likely candidates are the bootstrap rectifying diode (these love to become weak / open), bootstrap Zener, bootstrap capacitor, and current shunts. In the circuit you posted, this would be D128, D105, C115, and R239..R244. If you have spares in your parts bins, try replacing these diodes and the capacitor to see if that changes anything.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The current sensing resistors are sparkly clean, in fact everything seems to be. I checked every resistor and every junction, some out-of-circuit as well, including those you mentioned. I do find weird that the Vcc voltage is continuously varying between 8V and 16V once the circuit was revived but I assumed this is because it's still functioning out of specs. That said, according to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/58702/ high potential difference turns (between layers) are separated by insulation. Nearby shorted turns may be less obvious to detect.

Comment: Additionally, I disconnected the transformer and placed a 100kHz sine wave on the primary. I then measured both the feedback and auxiliary outputs in parallel with the primary. The scope indicated 720mVpp on the feedback output and 5.92Vpp on the primary, giving a roughly 8:1 ration. Similarly, I got 1.15mVpp on the aux output for a 5.76Vpp on primary, giving exactly 5:1. This may be withing specs, but I cannot tell for sure.

Comment: Did you mean 1.15Vpp on aux rather than 1.15mVpp? If so, then the transformer is indeed fine and the fault is somewhere else. Any shorted windings would've shorted out your 100kHz input waveform as well. A transformer's turns ratio can't go out of spec (you'd have to re-wind it), the only thing that can happen is a short or an open. So as long as you measure anything reasonable, there's no fault.

Comment: Have you checked capacitors yet, particularly electrolytics, C174, C175, C115, C168, C169, C532, etc.? They should be within tolerance (typically 20%) and reasonably low ESR. You may have to desolder them to tell individual health. Visual inspection should indicate no swelling or leakage.

Comment: @JonathanS. Yes, I meant 1.15Vpp. You may be right, as these transformers are designed for PWM with a duty cycle around 50% for the target output voltage.

Comment: @JonathanS. However, if any two-three (but not all) neighboring turns were to short, for various reasons, the transformer will continue to function but the whole system will be impacted. This could be the case for any primary/secondary. One aspect I'd like to underline is that the AUX voltage needs to remain within controller's specs for any load on the output. That doesn't seem to be the case anymore.

Comment: @TimWilliams The high-voltage capacitors C174, C175 are fine, no bulging/leaks and the rail is stable at around 340V. The C168, C169 were my prime suspects but are fine too. I measured them out of circuit with near zero ESR (by my measuring capabilities) and their capacity is unchanged. The C109 is missing from the circuit (forgot to mark it). To limit the debugging scope, I disconnected the 24V DC rail, making C532 irrelevant. I will replace C168 preemptively though.

Comment: @GameInstance If any turns at all on the transformer are shorted, it will *not continue operating at all*. You can view a shorted turn as an additional single-turn secondary, which is shorted out. Due to the high coupling of SMPS transformers, this means that if one turn is shorted out, *all windings will be shorted* at AC. So, if there was even just one shorted turn in your transformer, your entire 100kHz input signal would get shorted. It doesn't, though, and therefore we know for certain that the transformer doesn't have any shorts (and also no open-circuits).

Comment: _”I believe to be caused by its transformer”_ What leads you to suspect the transformer?

Comment: @JonathanS. That makes perfect sense and I feel embarrassed not realizing that sooner. Indeed, a shorted turn would produce a short which would either block and short the transformer or produce enough heat to make further internal damage. Although far-fetched, the said shorted turn may burn open but the chance of that happening in other place than the initial contact is slim.

Comment: @winny Jonathan S. asked the same question in his first comment. I answered afterwards and after several exchanges I realized I may be wrong in my assessment.

Comment: There is about one person per week here opening up their power supply, see a large transformer without any search results on the transformer numbers and assume it’s at fault. Less than one per year turns out to be the actual transformer. Perhaps it would be possible to have a wiki entry for such cases. Back to your supply, do you have access to an oscilloscope?

Comment: @winny Indeed, perhaps a wiki page for accumulating digested information from such threads would be interesting. I do have an oscilloscope and I used it for this debugging session. The Vds reflects a proper quasi-resonant wave-shape on start-up and after approx. 4ms it stops. Eliminating other external causes, I assumed controller was stopping for lack of FB signal due to the 12V output not reaching its target on time. I then altered the dividers for DET pin and VCC optocoupler and revived it (sort-of). This led me to suspect the transformer may be bad. JonathanS proved I may be wrong.

Comment: The soft start time is set to 5 ms, after that, either open loop, short circuit detection or lack of Vcc. Please measure both with an oscilloscope.

Comment: @winny To cope with the soft-start delta, I measured every signal of interest in parallel with the MOSFET's drain signal with a rising-edge trigger set at 480V and the playing with the time offset. Please check the scope captures I updated the post with (and do excuse the quality thereof).

Answer (score 3):

The inductance and resistance of a transformer can be measured with simple tools, for example a signal generator (sine preferred) and oscilloscope.  At least an AC voltmeter, or preferably vector voltmeter, is required, but the oscilloscope being so indispensable, it's commonly available.

I have several measurement methods on my website: [Calculators: LC Resonance | Seven Transistor Labs](https://www.seventransistorlabs.com/Calc/RLC.html#vec), in particular consider the vector method.  Set up a voltage divider between a signal generator, resistor, and DUT (device under test), and measure the voltage on both sides of the resistor.

(A simultaneous measurement across a resistor is required to get a phase-accurate reading without other signals.  We could also use a generator's trigger output and phase reference to that, *making sure to subtract unloaded and loaded angles*, to measure with minimum resistance i.e. the generator's (typically 50 ohm) output itself, which will extend sensitivity to somewhat lower |Z|.)

This appears to be a flyback supply.  Presumably, the transformer in question is a gapped ferrite design, and should have a Q factor on the primary in the ballpark of 100 or so.  Losses this low are difficult to measure accurately with a vector method, but we can rule out very low Q, and unexpectedly low L, as would be the case for a shorted turn.

(The resonant (RLC) method further down the page, is recommended for measuring higher Q accurately.)

Probably, unloaded primary inductance should be in the ballpark of upper 100s µH to low mH.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try that next as I have no other leads at this point.

Comment: The added waveforms look like the transformer and controller are both behaving more or less normally. Your problem seems to lie elsewhere.